# Verify a domain name in Azure Active Directory B2C doesn't work

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have Active Directory for B2C set up. I added my own domain, I configured my DNS and I click Verify, and I get "**Could not verify domain**".

Why?

**Additional facts:**

- Yes, I am quite adept at DNS of domains and added the TXT record properly
- Yes, I allowed plenty of time for DNS propagation (1 hr to... 2 weeks now)
- https://dnsquery.org/dnsquery/ shows expected values within minutes, just FYI:  "MyDomain.com. 3600 IN TXT "MS=ms34030xxx"
- No, I did not check "...configure for single sign on.." when adding the domain, as that is not supported for AD B2C.

**Possible Answers:**

- Perhaps B2C "Basic" (currently in Preview at time of this post) does not support adding a custom domain. If thats the case, why expose this in the Azure console??
- This is a legit MS bug, and I'm the only one hitting it ( yeah right :) )

Yes, this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380653/verify-a-domain-name-in-azure-active-directory), but the difference here is I am not asking HOW to configure DNS, I am asking WHY it doesn't work when configured. That and B2C might have different requirements or functionality as it is in preview. So please don't mark as dup unless indeed we determine I misconfigured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

support for domain verification for B2C tenants is on the roadmap but isn't available in the current preview.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, makes sense to me, and I kinda suspected.  Now, despite this being preview, might I suggest adding a message in the UI (or error) explaining such, when things aren't quite supported?  Caused a bit of confusion and self doubt on my setup :).